# Подсветка функций в jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Обновил себе компьютер, поставил новый python и все необходимые библиотеки, все новых версий.
Захожу в jupyter lab, в итоге вижу что-то странное с подсветкой.

Подсвечиваются ключевые слова, значение переменных, функции или классы из библиотек. Но, стандартные функции или например тип данных не подсвечивается, на скриншоте видно это наглядно.

[image: Пример проблемы]

Буду очень благодарен если кто-то знает в чем может быть проблема, и как это можно исправить самому в настройках?